# SQLAlchemy self reference model count

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I defined model that self-referenced.

```
follows = Table(
    'follows',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('follower_id', ForeignKey('users.id')),
    Column('following_id', ForeignKey('users.id')),
)


class User(Base, TimestampMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(BigInteger, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(Unicode(length=255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    nickname = Column(Unicode(length=255), nullable=True, unique=True)
    followers = relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=follows,
        primaryjoin=(follows.c.following_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(follows.c.follower_id == id),
        lazy='dynamic',
    )
    followings = relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=follows,
        primaryjoin=(follows.c.follower_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(follows.c.following_id == id),
        lazy='dynamic',
    )

    @hybrid_property
    def follower_count(self) -> int:
        return len(self.followers)

    @hybrid_property
    def following_count(self) -> int:
        return len(self.followings)
```

(follow database system like instagram)

To represent it to real db,

*users*

- id
- email,
- nickname
- created_at
- updated_at

*follows*

- follower_id
- following_id

If I search users by nickname, query would be

```
users = session.query(User).filter(User.nickname.like(nickname))
```

I want to order by follower count, so I querying like this.

```
users = session.query(User).filter(User.nickname.like(nickname)).order_by(func.count(User.followers))
```

But it throw errors.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'follows_1.following_id' in 'order clause'")
[SQL: SELECT users.created_at AS users_created_at, users.updated_at AS users_updated_at, users.id AS users_id, users.email AS users_email, users.nickname AS users_nickname
FROM users 
WHERE users.nickname LIKE %(nickname_1)s ORDER BY count(follows_1.following_id = users.id AND follows_1.follower_id = users.id)]
[parameters: {'nickname_1': 'hide'}]
```

Is there any solution here?

Thanks.

Comment: Without going deeper, `User.followers` is a `relationship` and as such will render as its `ON` clause in query context. You need a join and grouping, a subquery, or some such.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I think so too. But I wonder that is there any elegant way to using sqlalchemy method?